# Ударение в фамилии

Tags: ударение

Где правильно ставить ударение в фамилии Мастерова? МАстерова или МастерОва? Существуют ли правила расстановки ударения в фамилиях?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правил нет. Есть некая статистическая тенденция, что при ударении на первом слоге в двухсложной основе ударение на притяжательный ("фамильный") суффикс обычно не переносится. 
Т.е. от "м**а**стер" - более вероятна форма "М**а**стеров".

Но наверняка это может сказать только сам носитель фамилии.

Answer (score 5):

Правил нет, как хочет носитель фамилии, так и ставит. Или как привыкли все произносить по традиции в этой семье.

Answer (score 3):

Нет, таких правил не существует. Уж на что простая фамилия — ИванОв, однако есть и ИвАновы. Как того желает носитель фамилии.

Answer (score 1):

Правил нет. Но есть некая традиция. Если человеку не повезло появиться на свет с фамилией вроде Козёл, Петух, Баран и т.п., он никогда не произносит ее с привычным ударением. Всегда  такие фамилии звучат К**о**зел, Б**а**ран, П**е**тух...

Comment: А если уж *совсем* не повезло, то и ударение не спасает: Конь, Бык, Жук...

Я знаю человека по фамилии К**о**за.